# ssis http connection manager not listed in solution explorer

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I added a http connection manager to my SSIS project, did some additional work, then closed the IDE.

When I opened the IDE (VS 2010 10.0.40219.1 SP1 REL), the http connection manager had vanished.  When I examined the project's folder in Explorer, the .conmgr file is present.

Why is this occurring?  What do I need to get it to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not replicate the issue in this instance. Sometimes I did noted similar erratic behavior in VS while working with TFS.

The easiest way to add it back is:

**Right click on the Project in the solution explorer -> Add -> Existing Item** and Choose the .conmgr file.